# Running 2 java classes simultaneously from command prompt and eclipse

Tags: java, maven, javafx, command-prompt, communication

I'm currently working on a small project that requires a server and a small user interface, which I built with JavaFX. I have to start the user interface via the command prompt using mvn javafx:run (as you can see, I use maven to manage my dependencies). I start the server normally via Eclipse. This also works so far and both programs start up as desired. It just seems like they can't communicate with each other. The commands from the user interface do not arrive in the "actual" program. It seems like there are two separate versions running and not a unified one.

Here is my GUI main-class i start using mvn javafx:run:

```
public class FX extends Application  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {

            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../main/Scene.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            //scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }

}
```

And heres the corresponding controller:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private TextField senderField;

    @FXML
    private TextField receiverField;

    @FXML
    private TextField amountField;

    @FXML
    private TextField tfbpField;

    @FXML
    private TextField tflField;

    @FXML
    private TextField nonceField;

    @FXML
    private Button submitButton;

    @FXML
    void submitPressed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Submit Pressed");
        byte[] sender = SHA3Helper.hexToDigest(senderField.getText());
        byte[] receiver = SHA3Helper.hexToDigest(receiverField.getText());
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(amountField.getText());
        double tfbp = Double.parseDouble(tfbpField.getText());
        double tfl = Double.parseDouble(tflField.getText());
        Transaction transaction = new Transaction(sender, receiver, amount, 0, tfbp, tfl);
        System.out.println(transaction.getAmount());
        DependencyManager.getPendingTransactions().addPendingTransaction(transaction);
        for(int i = 0; i<100 ; i++) {
            System.out.println("Receiving test");
        }
        
    }

}
```

As you can see i implemented a simple for-loop to check whether "Receiving test" will also be displayed on eclipse or not - with the rusult that i can see it only in my cmd, not in Eclipse.

And here is the Tomcat that starts the actual program. Of course I start this one first.

```
public class Start
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        try
        {
            Tomcat tomcat = new Tomcat( );

            String webappDirectory = new File( "src/main/webapp" ).getAbsolutePath( );

            tomcat.setPort( 8080 );

            Context context = tomcat.addWebapp( "", webappDirectory );

            Tomcat.addServlet( context, "blockchain", new ServletContainer( new Application( ) ) );
            context.addServletMappingDecoded( "/blockchain/api/*", "blockchain" );

            tomcat.start( );
            tomcat.getServer( ).await( );
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace( );
        }
    }

}
```

Through dubugging I quickly found out that the problem lies in the communication between the two programs. Commands from the UserInterface do not reach the actual program.

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: That said: *'i implemented a simple for-loop to check whether "Receiving test" will also be displayed on eclipse or not'*. Why would you expect this to be displayed in Eclipse? As far as I can see you are just sending that to the console in the application that is running from the command line.

Comment: @James_D i thought because both main-methods use the same source. But how can i connect them then?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the "same source" here. There are two different source files with `main` methods in your post. You have two different applications, each running in their own JVM. To communicate between them, you would need to use some kind of network protocol; presumably HTTP (isn't that the entire reason you are using a Tomcat server in the first place????).

Comment: The UI is in one process and the web server is in another process, so you need some form of inter-process communication ([IPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)).  There is nothing in your provided code that demonstrates that you are attempting this.  As you are providing an HTTP server, the obvious mechanism for IPC is via HTTP calls as pointed out be James.

Comment: Off-topic, but `src/main/webapp` is not the appropriate path for use in a production application.  the `src` directory will only be available on a developer machine at development time, not on an end-user machine at application execution time.